# Getting fieldnames with QGIS expressions in same order as in attribute table (not alphabetical order)

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression, sorting, qgsexpression

**Context**

I want to get a list of field names of a layer using QGIS expressions. The function `attributes()` returns a `key:value` map of the attribute names and values. By default, the result is sorted alphabetically based on the attribute name. To get an alphabetical list of attribute names alone, I can use `map_akeys(attributes())`. This works fine. For those interested: the question arose with [this use case](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/415235/88814).

**Question**

How can the sort order be changed so that the order is not alphabetical, but reproduces the order in the attribute table?

*Alphabetical sort order does not correspond to the order in the attribute table:*

[image]

**What I tried**

A workaround for a custom order is ordering it manually with the new `array_prioritize` function (available [since QGIS 3.20](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-extended-array-expression-functions)). However, the sort order has to be defined manually and thus eliminates the advantage of automatically getting a list of all attributes with `map_akeys(attributes())`:

```
array_prioritize(
    map_akeys(attributes()),
    array ('grassland','forest','steppe','other','value5','value6','value7','value8','value9','value10','value11', 'value12')
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple custom function will do that :

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='GIS SE', referenced_columns=[])
def ordered_fields(feature, parent):
    return feature.fields().names()
```

To use : `ordered_fields()`

Comment: I like this part `group='GIS SE'` :)